# Android - Auto Scroll LinearLayout inside ScrollView?

Tags: android, scrollview, android-linearlayout

I have a vertical LinearLayout inside ScrollView. LinearLayout grows dynamically. I add fragments to this LinearLayout whenever a button is pressed(that is outside the scrollview), fragments are added, I also can see the scollbar but I want scroll bar to be auto scrolled to the last element that I have added. Currently there is no auto scrolling, I have to scroll it manually to see the last element.

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="557dp"
    android:layout_height="440dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView16"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.131"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear_layout_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        >

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: first of all use recyclerview instead of scrollview which gives you more options, then i think it's better to add fragments or other layouts as recyclerview items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use recyclerView instead of scrollView.
Here is the example to use scrollView to last.

```
mScrollView.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);

mScrollView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
    scroll.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
}}, 700);
```

Comment: Thanks man, it works. but may I know why postDelayed is needed? It doesnot work when postDelayed is not use. It takes me to 2nd last row but now the last row(when postDelayed is not used)

Comment: my pleasure dear.. we use post delay because it took some time to load function there should be some pause to get exact result . So , that's why we use post delay

Answer (score 1):

you can auto scroll on adding fragments.

```
scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0,scrollView.getBottom);
```

Comment: it scrolls down but not to last, instead goes to second last row